# How do I enable GD in PHP 5.1.4?

Tags: php, gd

I recently reinstalled PHP on my Win 7 machine.  In so doing, I upgraded from PHP 4 to PHP 5.1.4.  The GD functions no longer work.  I uncommented the php_gd2.dll line in php.ini:

```
;extension=php_fdf.dll
;extension=php_filepro.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll      <-- This line was originally commented
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_ifx.dll
```

But that didn't fix the problem.  phpinfo() says this about gd:

```
GD Support  enabled  
GD Version  bundled (2.0.28 compatible)  
FreeType Support  enabled  
FreeType Linkage  with freetype  
FreeType Version  2.1.9  
T1Lib Support  enabled  
GIF Read Support  enabled  
GIF Create Support  enabled  
JPG Support  enabled  
PNG Support  enabled  
WBMP Support  enabled  
XBM Support  enabled
```

This is myimage.htm:

```
<IMG SRC="myiamge.php" BORDER="1">
```

And this is myimage.php:

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_color = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_color = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "test", $text_color );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_color );
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

When I point my browser at myimage.htm, I see the icon of a broken image. What am I doing wrong? I'm a noob; be kind.

Comment: any errors logged on myimage.php?

Comment: 5.1.4? Really? Upgrade a bit further please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php 5.1.4 is quite ancient ( May 2006! ) - you should upgrade to at least php 5.4 or php 5.5 ( newest ). Then, you can follow the following [configuration steps](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php) to enable the GD library.

Comment: According to the site where I downloaded WinLAMP (http://winlamp.sourceforge.net/), the latest versions are:  Apache 2.0.58, PHP 5.1.4, and MySQL 5.0.22.  And while I have no way to prove it now, I know my code worked as expected in PHP 4.

Comment: Okay, I just went back to get the latest PHP.  Obviously Sourceforge is a dead site (I wonder who's paying the hosting bill).  Can someone point me to another site that offers WinLAMP for download?  Otherwise I'm stuck at 5.1.4.  Google links to Sourceforge as the top link, bleh.

Comment: 1) You really ought to learn how to install separate components, it's not that hard. 2) A complete package is http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: I would try it, but I want to work on my project rather than struggling with configuration settings getting the components of a SDK to play nice with each other.  And I don't want to risk breaking what does work right now, bleh.  Thanks for the advice :-)  I appreciate it, but I figured out a work-around today that doesn't require GD or dynamic image generation within PHP.